# magento 2 read csv from ftp returns a string and not an array

Tags: php, ftp, magento2

I'm working with Magento 2, I need to read a file through ftp connection. I can login to ftp but I cannot read the csv file. What I did so far (I cut all the unnecessary parts):

```
use Magento\Framework\File\Csv;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\Ftp;

class MyClass {
    protected $_csvprocessor;
    protected $_ftp;
    public function __construct(Csv $csvprocessor, Ftp $ftp) {
        $this->_csvprocessor = $csvprocessor;
        $this->_ftp = $ftp;
    }
    public function getCsv() {
        $conn = $this->_ftp->open($params); // this works, I can successfully login to ftp
        $filecsv = $this->_ftp->read($remotepathtofile); // this gets me the file but it is a string, not an array with the csv data
        $this->_csvprocessor->getData($remotepathtofile); // this doesn't work with remote file, only with local path (eg: magentoroot/var/import/file.csv)
    }
}
```

How can I read the csv as an array, as `$this->_csvprocessor->getData()` would return, but from remote file instead of local?

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the csv string. Try using the function "fgetcsv". See http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php.

Answer (score 0):

Below the code, you can use to read CSV file an array

```
    use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
    include('app/bootstrap.php');
    $bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
    $objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
    $objectManager1 = Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $directoryList = $objectManager1->get('\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList');
    $path = $directoryList->getPath('media');
    $state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
    $state->setAreaCode('frontend');
    $myarray = glob("Book1.csv"); 
    usort($myarray, create_function('$a,$b', 'return filemtime($a) - filemtime($b);'));
    if(count($myarray)){
        /*This will create an array of associative arrays with the first row column headers as the keys.*/
        $csv_map = array_map('str_getcsv', file($myarray[count($myarray)-1]));
        array_walk($csv_map, function(&$a) use ($csv_map) {
          $a = array_combine($csv_map[0], $a);
        });
        array_shift($csv_map); # remove column header
        /*End*/

        $message = '';
        $count   = 1;
        foreach($csv_map as $data){ 

your code....

}
```

Hope this will help you enjoy...

Answer (score 0):

You can dump the server file to your local.

```
   $filecsv = $this->_ftp->read($remotepathtofile, $destinationFilePath);
```

where $destinationFilePath is local file path.
Then use that local file.